# Suggested way to color a multirow table without package of colored tabulars

Tags: tables, color, cline

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


{\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}}
\arrayrulecolor{red}\toprule
\rowcolor{gray!60}Something & Number & \begin{tabular}{c}Something \\(splitted)\end{tabular}\\\midrule
\rowcolor{gray!20}\cellcolor{gray!60} & 1 & Here is a sentence automatically breakad\\
\rowcolor{gray!40}\cellcolor{gray!60}&2 & 2 secs  \\
\rowcolor{gray!20}\cellcolor{gray!60}&3 & 2 secs  \\
\rowcolor{gray!40}\cellcolor{gray!60}&4 & 2 secs  \\
\rowcolor{gray!20}\cellcolor{gray!60}&5 & 2 secs \\
\rowcolor{gray!40}
\multirow{-6}{*}{\cellcolor{gray!60}Multirow}&6 & 2 secs\\\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

That reproduces this table:

[image]

How can I solve the horizontal lines problem in a way that:
1) they don't appear at all inside the "multirowed" colored cell 
2) they don't "break" my red colored lines?

I don't want to use a `tabu` or `tikz` or similar solutions... but just looking for ways with regular tabular environment.

I am thinking about coloring the clines and may by make them thicker but I don't know the way.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I want too keep the horizontal (almost invisible) lines beetween the columns and also if possible between the other rows except of the ones inside the "multirowed" cell and around the red lines. If I can not keep them, at least to recreate them via `\cline{}` or something (but the vertical too).

I firstly thought a solution to create some colored `\clines` but didn't manage to find information on how to do it. Other solution and suggestions are appreciated.

@Bernard's answer is much appreciated but I have the next problems:

(B1) The separating lines between columns and the other rows are needed to separate between separate cells (like rows with numbers 3, 4 and 5 and like the separation between columns in the following picture):

(B2) The color around the `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\botomrule` (the red lines) is still white.

[image]

The above image has still the problems 1 and 2 [=(B2)] above but doesn't have the (B1)

Comment: So what do you want to remove? The white space around the red lines or the small "white lines" between columns and rows?

Comment: @TeXnician I am sorry I was not clear enough... I edited the post to make it clear. (I will be AFK for some hours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hack, playing with the optional argument of `\\` and  the overhang values of `\rowcolor`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\newcommand{\myrowcolor}[1]{\rowcolor{#1}[\tabcolsep][\dimexpr\tabcolsep+0.2pt]}

\begin{document}

{\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}}
\arrayrulecolor{red}\toprule
\myrowcolor{gray!60} Something & Number & \makecell{Something \\(splitted)}\\\midrule
\myrowcolor{gray!20}\cellcolor{gray!60} & 1 & Here is a sentence automatically breakad\\[-0.2pt]
\myrowcolor{gray!40} \cellcolor{gray!60}&2 & 2 secs \\[-0.2pt]
\myrowcolor{gray!20} \cellcolor{gray!60}&3 & 2 secs \\[-0.2pt]
\myrowcolor{gray!40} \cellcolor{gray!60}&4 & 2 secs \\[-0.2pt]
\myrowcolor{gray!20} \cellcolor{gray!60}&5 & 2 secs \\[-0.2pt]
\myrowcolor{gray!40}
\multirow{-6.5}{=}{\cellcolor{gray!60}Multirow}&6 & 2 secs\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in my opinion, the white strips around the booktabs rules, due to the padding of these rules (`\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`), doesn't look so nice. It would look better deleting this padding, and, say, slightly increasing `\arraystretch` to compensate.

*Edit*:

Here is a solution to remove the white strips around booktabs rules: I set the padding of these rules to `0pt`, and replace it with a minimal padding defined by `cellspace` at the top and bottom of all cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). I also introduced separating gray rules between rows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
\newcommand{\myrowcolor}[1]{\rowcolor{#1}[\tabcolsep][\dimexpr\tabcolsep+0.2pt]}
\newcommand{\myhhline}{\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{gray!60}}---}}


\begin{document}

{\centering
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{-0.1pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{-0.1pt}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}S{m{4cm}}}
    \arrayrulecolor{red}\toprule
    \rowcolor{gray!60} Something & Number & \makecell{Something \\(splitted)}\\\midrule
    \rowcolor{gray!20}\cellcolor{gray!60} & 1 & Here is a sentence automatically breakad\\[-0.4pt]
\arrayrulecolor{gray!60}\midrule
 \rowcolor{gray!40} \cellcolor{gray!60}&2 & 2 secs \\[-0.4pt]
 \midrule
    \rowcolor{gray!20} \cellcolor{gray!60}&3 & 2 secs \\[-0.4pt]
\midrule
    \rowcolor{gray!40} \cellcolor{gray!60}&4 & 2 secs \\[-0.4pt]
\midrule
    \rowcolor{gray!20} \cellcolor{gray!60}&5 & 2 secs \\[-0.4pt]
\midrule

\rowcolor{gray!40}
\multirow{-8}{=}{\cellcolor{gray!60}Multirow}&6 & 2 secs\\ 
\arrayrulecolor{red}\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but still gives some problems (I edited the question). If you think it can not be done with tabular environment and not tikz overlays and other similar hacks like this I can accept it as an answer after a few days.

Comment: @koleygr, how about one with tabu?

Comment: @JLeonV. I think the tabu can do it. But I would prefer a tabular solution if possible. (If I will not find an answer I will ping you... But I would like to see some really thin separating lines as in (B1)... I think that it is possible with tabu and easy)

Comment: @koleygr: I've posted a new code. Please see if it fits your requirements.

Comment: Perfect @Bernard... Thank you really much. I appreciate your effort but can not upvote again. 1000 Thanks.

Comment: @koleygr: That's unimportant. The main point for us is to feel helpful, and I really feel so with your nice comment.

Comment: @Bernard, this question came to me after an answer I gave to someone. I have similar feelings about helping and just noticed that can not do that and that it would be nice to find a way to do it (to learn more about tabular) and that it will be useful to the community too to have an answer on this problem. Our feelings are similar about helping but I can not help so much as you can because of lower knowledge. But I do my best when something is inside my abilities. Thanks for all again. Happy that learned from you though this.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show some results with tabu, because vertical thin lines are not solved, and please do not take this as imposing the package, but I think tabu is designed just to solve these problems as an extension from tabularx because it focuses on working with colors, of course it is not easy and it is not enough, it also has its problems, but it produces the following results.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}


%Packages for beautifull tables.
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Dummy text


\begin{document}
Some initial text.\\
\begin{table}[!h]
    \def\TableLineSize{1.5pt}
    \small
    \tabulinesep =1.5pt 
    \tabulinestyle{\TableLineSize red}
    \taburulecolor|red|{white}
    \arrayrulewidth=1mm \doublerulesep=1mm
    \taburowcolors[2] 2{gray!25 .. gray!50}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[1.2mc]X[1,mc]X[2.2,mc]} \firsthline\hline
        \rowcolor{gray!60}
        Something & Number & \makecell{Something \\(splitted)}\\ \firsthline\hline
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & Here is a sentence automatically breaked \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \multirow{-10}{*}{\cellcolor{gray}Multirow}
        & 1 & 2 secs  \\ \firsthline\hline
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{Usign tabu rowcolors to draw white and red huge lines}
    \label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \def\TableLineSize{0.75pt}
    \small  
    \tabulinesep = 1.5pt 
    \tabulinestyle{\TableLineSize white}
    \taburulecolor|red|{white}
    \arrayrulewidth=2pt \doublerulesep=2pt
    \taburowcolors[2] 2{gray!25 .. gray!50}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[1.2,mc]|X[1,mc]|X[2.2,mc]} \firsthline\hline
        \rowcolor{gray!60}
        Something & Number & \makecell{Something \\(splitted)} \\ \firsthline\hline
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & Here is a sentence automatically breaked  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \multirow{-10}{*}{\cellcolor{gray}Multirow}
        & 1 & 2 secs  \\ \firsthline\hline
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{Idem as table 1 but with thin separating lines}
    \label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]
some text
\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
\begin{table}[!h]
    \def\TableLineSize{1.5pt}
    \small
    \tabulinesep =1.5pt 
    \tabulinestyle{\TableLineSize red}
    \taburowcolors[2] 2{gray!25 .. gray!50}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[1.2mc]X[1,mc]X[2.2,mc]} \tabucline -
        \rowcolor{gray!60}
        Something & Number & \makecell{Something \\(splitted)}\\ \tabucline -
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & Here is a sentence automatically breaked  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\
        \multirow{-10}{*}{\cellcolor{gray}Multirow}
        & 1 & 2 secs  \\ \tabucline -
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{Normal 1.5pt red lines}
    \label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}

\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
\begin{table}[!h]
    \def\TableLineSize{0.75pt}
    \small
    \tabulinesep = 1.5pt
    \tabulinestyle{\TableLineSize white}
    \arrayrulewidth=1.5pt
    \taburowcolors[2] 2{gray!25 .. gray!50}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[1.2,mc]|X[1,mc]|X[2.2,mc]} \tabucline[red] -
        \rowcolor{gray!60}
        Something & Number & \makecell{Something \\(splitted)} \\ \tabucline[red] -
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & Here is a sentence automatically breaked  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \cellcolor{gray}& 1 & 2 secs  \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {2-3}
        \multirow{-10}{*}{\cellcolor{gray}Multirow}
        & 1 & 2 secs  \\ \tabucline[red] -
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{Idem as table 3 but with thin separating lines}
    \label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-2] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) tabu has strong abilities... Thanks for adding... I will find time to study from your code.

Answer (score 1):

For information, here is what can be done with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{M{2cm}M{3cm}M{4cm}}%
   [ 
     code-before = { 
                     \rowcolor{gray!60}{1}
                     \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!40}
                     \columncolor{gray!60}{1} 
                     \tikz [line width = 0.1pt, white]
                     \draw (1-|2) -- (2-|2)(1-|3) -- (8-|3) ;
                   }
   ]
\arrayrulecolor{red}\toprule
Something & Number & \begin{tabular}{c}Something \\(splitted)\end{tabular}\\\midrule
\Block{6-1}{Multirow} & 1 & Here is a sentence automatically breaked\\
 & 2 & 2 secs \\
 & 3 & 2 secs \\
 & 4 & 2 secs \\
 & 5 & 2 secs \\
 & 6 & 2 secs \\ \bottomrule 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]